# Can't get group without Destroyer's End achievement, advice

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am not in a raiding guild but have achieved an ilvl of 390 on my rogue. I would like to do Dragon Soul runs outside of LFR to get higher ilvl gear. The problem is, no one will take a toon without the Destroyer's End achievement. What are some things I can do to get through a normal DS run to get this achievement and get into subsequent groups? I'm sure it'll be much easier to get in, but every time I ask a group leader to make an exception (I assure them I will not roll on items just to get the achievement), I get blown off because of no achievement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own group, set your own rules.

However if you do not understand the encounters or have the ability to lead a group, this will not work out well for you.

Answer (score 1):

Other than continuing to hunt for that first group that will take you regardless of your achievement, which will then let you get your achievement, your other option is to use an addon like [Underachiever](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/underachiever) which lets you "fake" achievement links to chat.

I can't really recommend that, but given I've been in that situation (high ilvl, plenty of experience and achievement but on a different character) I can understand the frustration.